# how to use check box to toggle between links on the same button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint, checkbox

how do i use a html check box to toggle two different links in a html button?
(IE) a button  contains two links. with the use of a check box, if set to true, on click of button should go to xyz site and when check box false, on click of same button should go to abc site ?
Please help as i am new to j query. using this on a share point site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you,

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    var url=$('input:checked').length ? 'abc.com' : 'xyz.com';
    alert(url);// use window.location.href=url; to open that url
});
```

[Try Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kpULJ/)

Answer (score 0):

On checkbox change switch link href:
HTML

```
<input type="checkbox">
<a href="#" data-url1='lala' data-url2='lolo'>button</a>
```

JQUERY

```
$(function(){
    $('a').attr('href',$('a').data('url1'));

    $('input').on('change',function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('a').attr('href',$('a').data('url2'));
        }else{
            $('a').attr('href',$('a').data('url1'));
        }
     })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper code try and run it in your browser, you can even try this in jsfiddle

Two concepts here used is how to check the checkbox checked or not in jquery, there are many ways i illustrate the one way by using is(':checked')
and other is binding the click event of a button, which is quite simple. I hope you like it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" />
    <button id="myButton">Click</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#myButton').click(function(){
                if($('#myCheckbox').is(':checked')){
                    window.location.href = "http://www.google.co.in";
                }else{
                    window.location.href = "http://jforjs.com";
                }

            })
        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aswinlutchanah/LkSVS/)**

HTML

```
<input id="choice" name="choice" type="checkbox" data-yes="http://www.xyz.com" data-no="http://www.abc.com"/>
<button id="submit">submit</button>
```

jQuery

```
$('#submit').on('click',function(){
var url ='';
if($('#choice').is(':checked')){
    url = $('#choice').data('yes');
}
else{
    url = $('#choice').data('no');
}
alert(url);
//Uncomment below for redirecting automatically to the desired url
//location.href = url;
});
```